# Do webforms post to server on every page change?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This might be a very basic question that I should already know the answer to but I can not seem to validate it.

I would like to know, in a webforms app (DotnetNuke) there is a master form which is created by DotNetNuke

```
<form method="post" action="/buynow?mode=form" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In the app I have some fields and a button which fires a jQuery ajax POST to an external API. On the success of the post I use jQuery to redirect to a new page.

On this redirect will the form be posted to the server? I ask because in order to be PCI compliant I can not have the content of this form post to my server.

If it does post the form data by default is there a way to prevent it, or would it be just a matter of clearing the form fields before the redirect will solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use jQuery to redirect to a new page

Assuming you are using [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) to set the new URL, this will perform a GET of the new URL. No POST to the original URL (or anywhere else) will occur.

Many ASP.Net server controls cause a POST back to the same page, but these POSTs are almost always in response to a user action (a click, a dropdown change, etc.).

*In general*, you don't have to worry about postbacks occurring without your knowledge, but when in doubt, fire up a network sniffer (Firebug, Chrome tools, IE tools, etc.) to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. that is reassuring. I have tried to use the network activity tools but since there is a page load i don't get to see the activity as, atleast in the case of Chrome, the network activity page refreshes for each load.

Comment: No problem. I know what you mean about the Chrome tools. You could also use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if you want to get continuous (almost overwhelming amounts of) TCP traffic info.

Answer (score 2):

> I use jQuery to redirect to a new page

When you use redirect you are instructing the browser to perform a GET. In other words the browser won't perform a POST.